# Is there something like a detail view in JSF?

Tags: jsf

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
<f:detailview item="#{bean.getOne()}" var="p">
    <h:outputText value="#{p.name}" />
</f:detailview>
```

The detailview tag will get hold of one object in the scope so that child components can use its properties. Is there something like that in JSF?

Comment: What is this "detailview" supposed to do? Please expand your question, otherwise it will be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you merely need to "alias" a long EL expression into a short one.

You can use `<c:set>` for that.

```html
<html ... xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
...
<c:set var="p" value="#{bean.getOne()}" scope="request" />
<h:outputText value="#{p.name}" />
<h:outputText value="#{p.email}" />
<h:outputText value="#{p.birthdate}" />
...
```

Comment: isn't `<ui:param/>` also valid here? Why did you prefer `<c:set/>`

Comment: @Kerem: `<ui:param>` doesn't work that way in MyFaces and it wasn't clear if OP used Mojarra or MyFaces.

Comment: Ohh I did not think about the MyFaces. Thank you. +1